# XDocument.Parse preserving unwanted whitespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, whitespace

`XDocument.Parse` is retaining unwanted white space when parsing my XML. It appears that my XML is "not indented," which means that white space is retained regardless of whether or not I send in the `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace` flag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb551294(v=vs.110).aspx).

This means that when I have XML like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blah:Root xmlns:blah="example.blah.com">
  <blah:Element>
    value
  </blah:Element>
</blah:Root>
```

and then look at

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(blahXml);
xElement xEl = xDoc.Root.Element("Element");
string value = xEl.Value;
print value;
```

it will print `"\n    value\n"` instead of `"value"`.

How do I make `XDocument.Parse` always ignore white space regardless of whether or not I give it indented or not-indented XML?

Comment: Why don't you simply use  `xEl.Value.Trim()`

Comment: I could do that. I was hoping there was something built in so I wouldn't have to do .Trim() everytime I try to get a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White space between elements can be ignored (e.g.

```
<root>
  <foo>foo 1</foo>
  <foo>foo 2</foo>
</root>
```

can be parsed into a `root` element nodes with two `foo` child elements node if white space is ignored or into a `root` element node with five child nodes: text node, `foo` element node, text node, `foo` element node, text node), but if an element contains some text data that includes white space then it is considered important. So your only option is indeed to use a method like `Trim` in the .NET framework or like `normalize-space` in XPath to have the white space removed when you process the element.